# Flask: how to return different content to each user that might visit at the same time

Tags: python, html, flask, session

I am creating a small project (it does not have any form of log in to differentiate users). A user request a some stats and python generate a plot that is saved to a folder and then displayed in the HTML, the images are overwritten each time that a new request is done. As you can imagine if 2 users visit at the same time one user might see the other user request.

My question is mainly to find a way to easily approach this. Would you generate a random number and use it to write the file name? or get some user unique data from the browser?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Python

```
  coin_plot = sns.catplot(x='24hours', y='coin name', data=plot_df, kind='bar')
        plt.title('Coins and 24 hours market change')
        coin_plot.savefig("static/coin_plot.png")
```

HTML

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='coin_plot.png')}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

one approach would be to return the raw bytes from in memory as an image directly (skip save to disk)

```
import io
from flask import make_response
...
@app.route("/my_plot.png")
def my_plot():
     ....
     coin_plot = sns.catplot(x='24hours', y='coin name', data=plot_df, kind='bar')
     plt.title('Coins and 24 hours market change')
     buffer = io.StringIO()
     coin_plot.savefig(buffer, format="png")   
     buffer.seek(0)
     response = make_response(buffer.read())
     response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'image/png')
     response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='image.png')
     return response
```

Comment: hi thank you for the answer, and idea. However response = make_response(buffer.read()) does not seem to work as make_response is not assigned and throws an error